# getting '0b' in memory when trying to serialize object in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, binary

I am trying to serialize an object for sending in a socket, but for some reason, when i add to the string stream using <<, I'm also adding '0b' after it, i've tried looking for something that may cause this (such as a fault data type) but so far i came up with nothing.

this is my object before in memory before the serialization -

01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 03 0b 00 cc ff 00 00 00

this is the memory of the ostream that i use for the serialization -

01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 03 0b 03 0b 00 ff 00 00 00

this is the class itself and the overloading for serialization

`

```
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Header H)
    {
        os << H.CID;
        os << H.Version;
        os << H.FirstTwoCode;
        os << H.LastTwoCode;
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&H.Payload_size), sizeof(int));
        return os;
    }
```

```
class Header
{   
    UINT8 CID[CLIENTID_BYTE_SIZE];
    unsigned char Version;
    unsigned char FirstTwoCode;
    unsigned char LastTwoCode;
    int Payload_size ;
}
```

```
    Header::Header(UINT8 clientID[CLIENTID_BYTE_SIZE], int request_code, int PL_SIZE)
    {
        memcpy(CID, clientID, CLIENTID_BYTE_SIZE);
        Version = char(VERSION_NUMBER);
        FirstTwoCode = char(request_code / 100);
        LastTwoCode = char(request_code % 100);
        Payload_size = PL_SIZE;
    }
```

`

I've tried searching the web, and gone over my a lot of times, i think that it may have something to do with me saving integers inside chars, and the casting is doing something, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is in this line:

```cpp
os << H.CID;
```

It calls the unsigned char overload of (2) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2, which means it just writes the memory of your `Header` object until the first null byte.

To achieve what you actually wanted, you can do something like

```cpp
os.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(H.CID), CLIENTID_BYTE_SIZE);
```